# Not video player works at all Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: xubuntu, video

No of the video player work, vlc, smplayer, parole etc. etc.

I sometimes get an error, but mostly I get a screen with weird colors and a couple of weird sounds.

Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

By default Ubuntu disables some 3rd party sources, which might include some video playback.

From the Settings Manager option in menu open "Software & Updates". Try to check "Software restricted by copyright" and "Proprietary drivers" - then go to Other Software to check software from "Canonical Partners" and "Independent" which is some third-party software as well.

Answer (score 0):

After you do the above if you install the xubuntu-restricted-extras package that will take care of your codec issues.

You can get it through the software center or using a terminal you can:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install xubuntu-restricted-extras
```